# Is it a problem if @types/react and react have different versions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript is added to the version 16 react application created with create react app.
I have installed the latest v.18 version of @types/react and @types/react-dom, but I would like to know if it is a problem that the version is different from react.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes. The types might not reflect the actual structure if it’s for some entirely different version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, as you'll have TS types for React 18, but JS code for React 16. For example, you may be able to import a new feature from React 18 but get a runtime error because you only have React 16.

You can solve this by using `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` version 16 until you're ready to upgrade to React 18.

Answer (score 14):

`npx typesync` will resolve type syncing issues. The script checks your package.json and searches the web for the @types version of your package, if one is not already installed. This may also remove the @types packages should you no longer need it.

You can go a step further and add this in your package.json:

```
“postinstall”: “npx typesync”
```

Now every time you install or update your packages you’ll automatically run the postinstall script!

Comment: typesync seems really handy tool!
Thank you for sharing this information!

Comment: Using typesync in `postinstall` messed with rebasing for me. It didn't deal with conflicts at all. If you want to use it like this be wary

Comment: Mind sharing more about this?

Comment: Adding a [link to docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typesync)